# Java:What is wrong with this regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to get the text inside a tag i.e. `<text>`. I am doing:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\<).*(?=\\>)");
```

I think that this says: any character 0 or more times that before is a `<` (positive lookbehind) and followed by `>` (positive lookahead).

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);  
if (!m.matches()) continue; //Called in a for loop
```

But there is no match for eg the input `<text> some other stuff here`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `m.matches()` but `m.find()`.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) on `matches()`:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

Comment: Thanks!But I am not sure now what `matches` does.I mean what is the entire region in this case

Comment: @user384706 The entire region is the entire string you want to match, i.e. the entire content of `data` in your case.

Answer (score 5):

When you are using `matches()`, the entire input string must match the expression. If you want to find substrings, you may use `find()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to match:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<text> Some Value </text> <a>  <testTag>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(\\w.*?)>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while(m.find()){
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your regular expression, but this works for me:

```
String text = "<text>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*<(.*)>.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

this displays:

```
true
text
```

Is that what you need?